# Making a window resizable in Java using KeyEvent

Tags: java, swing, resize, window, toggle

It has been a while since I last programmed in Java and I have unfortunately almost forgotten everything I knew...Just so you know, I did a Google search and couldn't find anything I needed for this particular problem. I want to make my window toggle between full screen and a window. Here is my code...

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

   ImageIcon i= new ImageIcon("icon.png");
   Image ico=i.getImage();

   public void create(){
    this.setSize(800,600);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.setIconImage(ico);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setTitle("MYTITLE");
   }

   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
   }

   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
   }

   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
    if (e.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_F1){
        this.setSize(1280,1024);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
    }else{
        this.setSize(800,600);
    }
   }
}
```

It makes the window, but I cannot get it to resize the window and I have imported the event library for those of you wondering. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: 1) you never add a KeyListener to a component, so there's no way that it could work, 2) You shouldn't even be using KeyListener. Better to use Key Bindings as per MadProgrammer (1+). Most important, you're trying to solve two issues at the same time, which is why you're not going to find solutions by Googling. Instead solve the issues in isolation -- 1) getting key strokes in a Swing GUI and 2) changing the GUI from window to full and back.

Comment: Like I said, it has been a while since I have programmed and I am doing it for college. I am kinda switching back and forth from previous projects I had trying to relearn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, take a look at [the key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), this will give you greater control over the focus level required to generate key events.

Second, take a look at [JFrame#setExtendedState](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29), which will allow you to control in a platform independent manner, the size state of the window

Comment: +1 for Key Bindings. You will probably want to add the Key Bindings to the `root pane` of the frame. You can use `frame.getRootPane()` to access the root pane.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use e.getKeyChar in keyTyped. It returns nothing. Either shift the process to keyPressed method or do something like this

```
ArrayList<Integer> keysDown = new ArrayList<>();
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        keysDown.add(e.getKeyCode());
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        keysDown.remove(keysDown.indexOf(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if(keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_F1)) {
            //Do Something
        }
    }
```